# IdentityServer4: Failed to retrieve access token, An error was encountered while handling the remote login

Tags: oauth, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to build a basic project using IdentityServer authentication. The past days I've been picking up bits and pieces from everywhere, but mostly from [FullStackMarc](https://fullstackmark.com/post/21/user-authentication-and-identity-with-angular-aspnet-core-and-identityserver).

At the moment I'm able to get to the point where the Client-application requests a token from the IdentityServer. Then IdentityServer redirects to the `RedirectUrl`, which is allowed by the OAuth-client. That's where I'm getting the following error:

[image: Failed to retrieve access token, An error was encountered while handling the remote login]

Reproduction:

1. git clone https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/AngularASPNETCoreOAuth
2. cd AngularASPNETCoreOAuth\src\AuthServer\AuthServer.Infrastructure
3. dotnet ef database update --context AppIdentityDbContext
4. Now you should have a new database in LocalDB
5. Open and launch both solutions
6. You need to create a user for now (with PostMan)

```
POST https://localhost:44348/api/Account HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Bob",
    "email": "bob@example.com",
    "password": "Aze123°}"
}
```

7. Put a breakpoint at AuthServer → AccountController:238
8. The debug session of the ResourceAPI initially launches `https://localhost:44344/api/Profile/login`
9. This action returns the challenge to login with my IdentityServer instance at `https://localhost:44348/Account/Login`
10. Here you can login with:

    - Username: **bob@example.com**
    - Password: **Aze123°}**
11. The application executes the Login-HttpPost action, which redirects successfully to the RedirectUrl with the `state` and `code` appended to the querystring
12. Now IdentityServer requests a token by POSTing to `Account/Token`
13. This calls the `RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync` method, sending a request to `https://localhost:44348/connect/token`
14. This request completes successfully, with a bearer token in the result. So `tokenResponse.AccessToken = ey...`

[image: The tokenResponse.AccessToken is defined]

15. The Token-request completes with 200 response containing an `IdentityModel.Client.TokenResponse`
16. Next, you're redirected to `https://localhost:44344/signin-my-auth-server` with the `code` and `state` queryparams
17. Next, instead of handling the signin-request, the following exception is thrown (as shown in the image):

> Failed to retrieve access token
>
> An error was encountered while handling the remote login
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

I would post my source code, but it's really a lot. It's available at https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/AngularASPNETCoreOAuth. I've put breakpoints at the following positions:

- AccountController:228
- AccountController:238
- AccountController:245

Why isn't Identity able to read the access token from the response returned from the `https://localhost:44348/Account/Token` response?

EDIT:

I'm getting the following error in the console, but these errors appear before the last breakpoint is hit and the workflow is still successful up until then. So I don't think this is a breaking issue in this case.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'PersistedGrants'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:42c02e4f-a9a8-4a0e-929b-eed3008cd38b
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.TokenCleanup: Error: Exception removing expired grants: Invalid object name 'PersistedGrants'.
```

And off course the table `PersistedGrants` doesn't exist, and creating another migration does not modify the database structure.

EDIT 2:

This is the output of the logfile I'm getting after I added Serilog:

```
2021-01-03 16:34:52.005 +01:00 [INF] Starting IdentityServer4 version 3.0.1.0
2021-01-03 16:34:52.184 +01:00 [INF] Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
2021-01-03 16:34:52.184 +01:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
2021-01-03 16:34:52.184 +01:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
2021-01-03 16:34:52.184 +01:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
2021-01-03 16:34:52.184 +01:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
2021-01-03 16:34:52.186 +01:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
2021-01-03 16:34:52.375 +01:00 [DBG] Starting grant removal
2021-01-03 16:34:52.460 +01:00 [DBG] Login Url: /Account/Login
2021-01-03 16:34:52.462 +01:00 [DBG] Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
2021-01-03 16:34:52.462 +01:00 [DBG] Logout Url: /Account/Logout
2021-01-03 16:34:52.462 +01:00 [DBG] ConsentUrl Url: /consent
2021-01-03 16:34:52.462 +01:00 [DBG] Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
2021-01-03 16:34:52.462 +01:00 [DBG] Error Url: /home/error
2021-01-03 16:34:52.462 +01:00 [DBG] Error Id Parameter: errorId
2021-01-03 16:34:58.811 +01:00 [DBG] Augmenting SignInContext
2021-01-03 16:34:58.812 +01:00 [DBG] Adding idp claim with value: local
2021-01-03 16:34:58.812 +01:00 [DBG] Adding amr claim with value: pwd
2021-01-03 16:34:58.821 +01:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
2021-01-03 16:35:03.096 +01:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2021-01-03 16:35:03.100 +01:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2021-01-03 16:35:03.100 +01:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2021-01-03 16:35:03.101 +01:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2021-01-03 16:35:03.189 +01:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery
2021-01-03 16:35:03.189 +01:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
2021-01-03 16:35:03.190 +01:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
2021-01-03 16:35:03.191 +01:00 [DBG] Start key discovery request
2021-01-03 16:35:03.228 +01:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
2021-01-03 16:35:03.232 +01:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Token, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
2021-01-03 16:35:03.232 +01:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
2021-01-03 16:35:03.234 +01:00 [DBG] Start token request.
2021-01-03 16:35:03.236 +01:00 [DBG] Start client validation
2021-01-03 16:35:03.238 +01:00 [DBG] Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2021-01-03 16:35:03.239 +01:00 [DBG] Start parsing for secret in post body
2021-01-03 16:35:03.240 +01:00 [DBG] Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser
2021-01-03 16:35:03.240 +01:00 [DBG] Secret id found: CarfacPlusClient
2021-01-03 16:35:03.247 +01:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client CarfacPlusClient succeeded.
2021-01-03 16:35:03.252 +01:00 [DBG] Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator
2021-01-03 16:35:03.252 +01:00 [DBG] Client validation success
2021-01-03 16:35:03.255 +01:00 [DBG] Start token request validation
2021-01-03 16:35:03.258 +01:00 [DBG] Start client credentials token request validation
2021-01-03 16:35:03.272 +01:00 [DBG] CarfacPlusClient credentials token request validation success
2021-01-03 16:35:03.280 +01:00 [INF] Token request validation success, {"ClientId":"CarfacPlusClient","ClientName":"Angular SPA","GrantType":"client_credentials","Scopes":"email","AuthorizationCode":null,"RefreshToken":null,"UserName":null,"AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses":null,"Tenant":null,"IdP":null,"Raw":{"grant_type":"client_credentials","scope":"email","client_id":"CarfacPlusClient","client_secret":"***REDACTED***"},"$type":"TokenRequestValidationLog"}
2021-01-03 16:35:03.297 +01:00 [DBG] Getting claims for access token for client: CarfacPlusClient
2021-01-03 16:35:03.360 +01:00 [DBG] Token request success.
```

All seems fine to me...

Comment: IdentityServer will tell why it was reject in its log, do explore the log file. What does it say?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well I can't find a log file, but I'm only getting a non-related error in the console

Comment: you have to configure ASP.NET Core where to send the logs from ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer. Typically you use Serilog for that. You see it being configured in Program.cs in the IS4 templates, like here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis/src/IdentityServer/Program.cs

Comment: I typically send all my logs to Seq at https://datalust.co/ that is a logging solution created by the Serilog author

Comment: Are you sure you have created the PersistedGrants table?

Comment: No there is no `PersistentGrants` table created by efcore

Comment: I tried a last-resort and created the `PersistentGrants` table myself. The errors are now gone from the Output window, but the symptoms are still the same...

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks for the reply. I've added my Serilog output. All the calls seem to succeed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226779/discussion-between-tore-nestenius-and-pieterjan).